# What is the difference between executable files?

Tags: c, linux, elf, objcopy

I have the following C program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("hhhh");
    return 0;
}
```

Commands to compile, copy and compare:

```
$ gcc print.c -o a.out
$ objcopy a.out b.out
$ cmp a.out b.out
```

I have compiled this program and created an executable. Then, I have used the `objcopy` command to  make a copy of the executable. But, when I compare these files, I get this:

> files differ: byte 41, line 1

How can I know what contents are missing?
Any help or pointers would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Also you may want to specify Linux flavor you are using. I don't think this behavior is reproducible on all Linux.

Comment: VTC because incomplete info: no identification of the compiler, OS/arch, what the difference is, etc.

Comment: Why do you think something is missing? It just says they differ. I suspect it's a timestamp.

Comment: I am using cent OS yes this is not producible because I am testing it for the other compiler I am just want to know how we can find where the difference is ?

Comment: Byte 41 in the 64 bit [ELF header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) is a part of the section header offset field (`e_shoff`); in the 32 bit ELF header is a part of the header size field (`e_ehsize`). You should probably post a link to those files (or at least, a hex dump of the first 512 bytes or so) to let us help you.

Comment: Also, even just doing `cmp -l a.out b.out` and posting the output could prove valuable.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? What is the actual problem? Does `a.b` have any issues? If you want an identical copy use `cp` instead.

Comment: when I take hexdump of two files and then find the difference then I found following difference can anyone please tell me know what it means                                                                                                          -0002310 0008 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
+0002310 0008 0000 0000 0000 0008 0000 0000 0000

Comment: Offset 0x2310 is way beyond the length of the binary generated with my gcc, so it's not in the initial header. Again, either you upload your binaries or there's no way we can help you.

Comment: @Matteo Italia how can I attach my hexdump files ?

Comment: I found the difference. The difference is EntSize of .init_array section is 0 bytes in a.out file and it is 8 bytes in the b.out file can anyone know why this difference is coming ?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I know what contents are missing?

What made you believe that any contents *is* missing?

The way `objcopy` works is:

1. parse the contents of the input file into internal representation.
2. copy parts of the original file to the output file as instructed by options

Nowhere does `objdump` guarantee that when "copy entire file" is given, the result will be bit-identical.

In particular, non-loadable sections could be reordered or changed in other ways.

> The difference is EntSize of .init_array section is 0 bytes in a.out file and it is 8 bytes in the b.out

The `EntSize` of 0 doesn't make sense for a non-empty section. If you really have such section in your `a.out`, it's likely that your linker has a bug.